# Casting generic type to a subtype

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have an ArrayList<Number> which I read out of a file. But I need it to be an ArrayList<Integer>. I know all the Numbers are Integers, so I thought I could do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
nubers.add( 1 );

// cast the list<Number> to a list<Integer>
ArrayList<Integer> ints = (ArrayList<Integer>)numbers;
ints.add( 2 );
```

However, this causes an compile error. But if I first cast numbers to an Object, the code runs perfectly (except of-course for the unsafe cast warning).

```
ArrayList<Integer> ints = (ArrayList<Integer>)(Object)numbers;
```

So why does the compiler complain at my cast when it's a valid cast?

Note: I'm not asking for a solution but for an explanation of why the cast does not compile.

**Bonus question:**

Thanks for your explanations, but they make me wonder why [this line](https://github.com/watabou/pixel-dungeon/blob/master/src/com/watabou/pixeldungeon/items/Heap.java#L363) can compile in some environments? A brief summary of the line:

A Collection<Bundleable> is being cast to Collection<? extends Item> where Item implements Bundleable.

Comment: That is because the two classes don't use the same amount/type of data, rather create a for loop going through the numbers list and then adding it the ints list indevidually. this can be done by doing `numbers.get(index).intValue();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type information of list is not available at runtime, i.e, generics are not reifiable. So at runtime, the cast will anyways work, as it's just like this:

```
ArrayList ints = (ArrayList)numbers;
```

No worries. But if allowed, the cast will result in issues down the line, like in below modified code of yours:

```
ArrayList<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
nubers.add( 1.0 );

// cast the list<Number> to a list<Integer>
ArrayList<Integer> ints = (ArrayList<Integer>)numbers;
Integer x = ints.get(0);  // trouble here
```

Basically you added a `double` type to a `List<Number>` which is perfectly fine. If compiler allowed the casting, then it will also pass at runtime.

Going further, the last line (commented one) will fail with `ClassCastException`, because you're just trying to assign a `Double` type to `Integer` type. That's the reason compiler doesn't allow to do such casts. And you should not ignore unchecked cast warnings by compiler in case of generics (even though that is warning).

Comment: I accept that it is dangerous practice, but I would have thought that java would still let me do it with a warning. I don't see why it should be an error when it is valid a runtime

Comment: @mdsimmo It will let you cast to and from raw types, or unbounded wildcard types with warnings. But this case where compiler for sure knows the issue, will be error.

Comment: It can produced a further error at runtime if you put elements that are not `Integer`s... Such a cast is a common source of confusion, this is why it is reported as error.

Comment: Thanks all. Can you please explain the bonus question?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following declaration:

```
ArrayList<Number> numbers;
```

the `ArrayList` `numbers` could later be instantiated with **any** generic which extends the `Number` class, such as:

```
numbers = new ArrayList<Float>();
```

Now, you can see the problem with the following cast:

```
ArrayList<Integer> ints = (ArrayList<Integer>)numbers;
```

But `numbers` contains `Float`s, not `Integer`s.  By the way, making the cast to `Object` **does** compile, but does so with a warning:

```
ArrayList<Integer> ints = (ArrayList<Integer>)(Object)numbers;

Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

The compiler is complaining about an unchecked cast, because it correctly deduces that the generic types may not match.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that generics are not *real* types, there is type erasure for them. So the compiler tries to verify many things about the way you use generics before compiling to bytecode. As `ArrayList<Integer>` is not as subtype of `ArrayList<Number>` (even if: `Integer` is subtype of `Number` or your list of `Number`s is full of `Integer`s), the compiler complains about the *direct* cast as it may be too dangerous (not really related types).
In the second case, you pass over the compiler type-checking in some way, because of course every of your types is subtype of `Object` and the compiler can't enforce a rule, but he can warns you about the downcast...